# Trying to read string from text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file which I need to read string which is located in line 1 and col22 using c# as shown in the image below .

[image]

Is there a way to do it with c#?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: How about reading the first line and skipping the first 21 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :** You can use `File.ReadAllLines()` method to read allthe lines from the file.
**Step 2:** Yoc can take the first Line returned by `File.ReadAllLines()` method and apply `Substring()` method to get the required part.

Try This:

```
String strContent=File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt")[0];
strContent=strContent.Substring(22,strContent.Length-22);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\YourFile.txt").First().Substring(21)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is always the same position..

```
 char[] b = new char[30];
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("..\\..\\Program.cs");
 sr.Read(b, 0, 30);

 char ch22 = b[21];
```

For ABSOLUTE position, you can open the file, move to postion 22 and get the byte there. This way, you do not have to read in any data that you don't actually need.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\..\\Program.cs", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(21, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] b = new byte[1];
fs.Read(b, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code but first of all you need to read file line by line, and put that line in some string variable. the separate the words in string (you have blank spaces ' ' as an indicator of the start of new word) and select the 22 word. Read how to do it here http://www.dotnetperls.com/split